# Game Maker Studio: Admob Banner Ad Showrates are Continuously Dropping

Tags: android, ios, admob, banner, game-maker

I have an Android & iOS app that I created with GM:S. I am using relatively newer versions to build my game. (v1.4.1683 for iOS, v1.4.1711 for Android) I use Admob to monetize the apps and I use the Google Play Services Extension from the Marketplace for the ad-integration. However, because I had no problems with the extension so far; I was using the version of the extension that I downloaded some 5 months ago.

Now to the problem: Traditionally I had 98,5-99,5% show rate on my banner ads. However, starting from the beginning of this month; my show rate began to decline and the trend seems like it will continue like this. It is somewhere around 96,5% now. This applies for both iOS and Android. Here is the graph of 2016 to see the decline better.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uFGs.png

Was there an update to the Admob SDK that I was unaware of that might be the reason for this? What other issues can cause a problem like this?

Also like I have said before; I was not updating my Google Play Services extension as I had no problems whatsoever with it before. Should I update the extension. And is there a way I can test the success updating the extension without going live first?

Any alternative thoughts and ways to fix this are also appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having a similar problem.  I post a question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938459/sudden-drop-in-admob-show-rate) and I am still waiting for any hint.  Please let me know if you found a solution.  Thanks